# google sheet custom function to multiply columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a google app script to fetch a range, multiply one column in the range by another column in the range, then output to a different column within the original range.  This should be simple, but I can't figure it out.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:B22").getValues();
  var newData = []
  for (i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var multiply = row[0] * row[1]
    newData.push(multiply)
  }
   sheet.getRange(1,3,22,1).setValues(newData)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the recommendation, but that didn't work unfortunately.  The reason I'm not using the arrayformula function is because this is actually a small piece of a larger, more complicated function.

What did end up working is pushing the "multiply" variable into newData as an array by putting it in brackets.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:B22").getValues();
  var newData = []
  for (i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var multiply = row[0] * row[1]
    newData.push([multiply])
    Logger.log(newData)
  }
   sheet.getRange(1,3,22,1).setValues(newData)

}
```